# Law of large numbers over each mean of $h$ consecutive variables

Tags: pr.probability, limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with finite mean $\mu$.

The (weak) law of large numbers says that
$$\forall\varepsilon > 0\quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{Pr}\!\left[\,\left|\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu\right| > \varepsilon\,\right] = 0.$$

Thus, as $n \to \infty$, we have that $\tfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is close to $\mu$ with high probability.

I'm interested to know if also each means of $h$ consecutive $X_i$ tends to be close to $\mu$ with high probability, assuming that $h$ is not to small compared with $n$, say $h \geq a n$ for some fixed constant $a \in (0,1)$.

Is some result of the form
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \forall a \in (0,1) \quad \lim_{n \to +\infty} \mathbf{Pr}\!\left[ \min_{\substack{an \leq h \leq n \\ 0 \leq i \leq n - h}}\left|\frac1{h}\sum_{j = 1}^h X_{i + j} - \mu\right| > \varepsilon\right] = 0$$
known?

Comment: I think this is essentially the same statement as before. Let's say $h=n/10$. Then you can consider the 100 consecutive segments of length $n/100$ each. These averages will be within $\epsilon$ of $\mu$ for all large $n$, with large prob (by the original law of weak numbers, applied to each of these 100 segments). This means that averages over segments of length $h$ are about within $10\epsilon$ of $\mu$.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit sloppy. I think I really need to subdivide into $N\gg 1$ segments of length $h/N$, and how large an $N$ I need will depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: in any case this follows from the strong law of large numbers: for fixed $\delta>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that with probability at least $1-\delta$ the partial sums $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ satisfy $|S_n-\mu n|<\delta n$ for all $n>N$. So, if $an>N$, we get $|S_{i+h}-S_h-\mu h|<2\delta n$ under your restrictions on $i$ and $h$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov It seems to me that your reasoning does not use the hypothesis $h > an$, but only that $h \to +\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$. Is it right?

Comment: @JerryAZ it uses: we need the estimate $\varepsilon h$, but get only $2\delta n$. This is essentially the same if $h>an$ for fixed $a$

Comment: @JerryAZ and if we have only $h\to \infty$, this is obviously false even for the coin tossing (i.i.d 1/2-Bernoulli): there are arbitrarily large sequences of tails.